# Is it possible for non-residents to shoot at a range in the State of Georgia (US)?

Tags: usa, legal, activities, georgia-usa, firearms

I am interested in going to a range to shoot both hand guns and rifles while in Georgia. Is it legal to do this in Georgia as a non-resident, and if it is legal, is it common for ranges to deny entry to non-residents?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is absolutely legal to shoot at a range as long as you either shoot their guns or bring your own **legal** firearm to the range **provided your weapon meet range's restrictions.**

For example: [Sandy Spring Shooting Range](http://www.sandyspringsshootingrange.com/) will rent you a firearm, similar is available from [Shooters of Columbus](http://www.shootersofcolumbus.com/range.asp).

Normally the only thing that you need to have with you is a valid photo ID.

You can probably use [Where to Shoot Site](http://wheretoshoot.org) to limit the list of shooting ranges.

Comment: *"bring your own legal firearm"* -- isn't it the case that non-resident in normal circumstances cannot legally own firearm in US?

Comment: @vartec You cannot register a firearm in the US, however, you can bring a firearm into the US as long as proper permits and declarations are issued and bring it with you to the range.  Competitive shooters do it all the time.